# App isnt installed widget android

Tags: android, widget, emulation

Trying to test a widget.The Widget appear  in the widget tab when I click on it, I get app is not installed toast message in **Emulator**
I don't really understand how widget works , so one more sub-question : I followed http://kasperholtze.com/android/how-to-make-a-simple-android-widget/ tutorial -> now I have this source code , perhaps I need to run it even once from an activity , how the code is compiled into the widget anyway?

Below is the manifest.

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".TimeWidget"
        android:label="Time" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE"/>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/time_widget_provider" />
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.ass3.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ConfigurationActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="IncCallHistory" android:label="Incoming Call History"></activity>
    <activity android:name="TimeWidget" android:label="Time Widget"></activity>
</application>
```